# Microsoft Word - Replace date created field with date printed on print

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2016

I've been unable so far to find a solution to this. I need to find a way to replace the date created field with date printed when someone tries to print the document.

To make it more of a challenge, I have the issues below:

- This has to only be a temporary change as our users have a habit of accidentally saving which would override the correct date.
- We can't use VBA as our system has a meltdown if there is any in the document.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I've hit a bit of a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know that there is a true non-vba solution.

Here is my page on the available [Date fields in Word](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart).

### You could change the CREATEDATE field to a DATE field.

### Consider using a template rather than a document.

Re-use of documents is not a good idea in general. If you use a Word Template, a new document would be created and the CREATEDATE field would reflect that date. Here is my page on [Templates in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm). If you are not using templates you are missing out on one of Word's key tools.